# Get the output Dir of my TFS Build in a property usable by my project

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, msbuild, tfsbuild

I have this command in a post build event:

> if $(ConfigurationName) == Release "$(SolutionDir)Tools\NuGet.exe" pack "$(ProjectDir)MyProject.Contracts.nuspec"

This works just fine when I compile in Visual Studio.  But when my build runs this it fails.  That is because someone somewhere thought it was a good idea to have builds on TFS not run the same as a build on a dev machine.

In this case it is the fact that all output files are grouped into a common "Binaries" folder.

So, my question is this:

**Is there a property I can use (instead of ProjectDir) that will allow me to reference the output location of the build?**

Meaning that it will point to  the binaries folder when running a TFS build and point to my normal output when doing a normal Visual Studio based build.

I tried $(OutDir) but it equated to "bin\Release\"
**UPDATE:** I tried to use $(OutDir) but Visual Studio fails with the partial path it provides.  Is there something that could be used with $(OutDir) to give a full path for both Visual Studio and TFS builds?

In case it matters:

- TFS version is TFS 2010 (Latest releases installed)
- Build Machine and Dev Machine are both running Windows 7 and VS 2010 Ulitmate

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$(OutDir)` should resolve to your `bin\debug` or `bin\release` etc for local builds, on the build server this will be resolved to the `Binaries` folder.

So yes, `$(OutDir)` should be the right one to use.

Comment: But I need the full path.  The Visual Studio fails my command in the post build event with a partial path.

Comment: Hmm, so `$(OutDir)` would work on TFS but not locally? I'd maybe check for `$(DevEnvDir)` or something as well, if it's not installed, should be blank, then you can use `$(ProjectDir)`, otherwise use `$(OutDir)`. Bit hacky and if you've got VS installed on the build server it probably won't work either as it would also try to resolve the `$(ProjectDir)`.

Comment: I found `if $(TeamBuildConstants) == _TEAM_BUILD_` to check if I am in a team build.  (By the way, that lead me to discover that the problem is actually in my nuspec file.)